# Is it possible to set a custom layout for a key in keyboard?

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I need to create a custom keyboard for android with specific design and behavior of keys on it (design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkv8k.jpg). I think this is possible only with creating a custom interface of keys but I didnt found any paths to set custom views for them.

Can I set (and how I can do it if it possible) custom layout for keys on my keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved. Answer is simple - just make your own [Keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java) and [KeyboardView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/b798689749c64baba81f02e10cf2157c747d6b46/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java) classes in project then rewrite onDraw method in KeyboardView. After this, you can change default keyboards classes to yours in your keyboard service.

Comment: could you provide a sample code for this